# JavaScriptSerializer and MVC - struggling with JSON

Tags: c#, json

I've been trying to figure out why some of my tests haven't been working (TDD) and managed to track it down to serialization of a class, but I'm not sure why it's not working. There are two flavours, a simple version and a more complex version, the slightly more complicated one involves having an array of values within the Parameter.Value.

The simple version, I've got a class that can be serailzied using the `JavaScriptSerializer` (I'm assuming this is how MVC works when it generates JSON). The structure it produces looks like this:

```
{
   "Name": "TestQuery",
   "QueryId": 1,
   "Parameters": [
   {
        "Name": "MyString",
        "DataType": 0,
        "Value": "A String",
        "IsArray": false
    }],
   "Sql": "SELECT * FROM Queries"
}
```

There are 3 C# classes `Query`, `ParameterCollection` (which is a `KeyedCollection<String, Parameter>`) and a `Parameter`. All of these are marked up with `DataContract`/`DataMember` attributes and serialize via the `DataContractSerializer` without any problem.

The `JavaScriptSerializer` however, serializes the object correctly to the JSON above, but upon deserialization I have no Parameters, they just seem to get missed off.

Does anyone have any idea why these fails, and what I might be able to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `KeyedCollection<String, Parameter>`? You have an array, not dictionary, so your JSON should match the following structure:

```
public class Query
{
    public int QueryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sql { get; set; }
    public Parameter[] Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DataType { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsArray { get; set; }
}
```

and then you will be able to deserialize it without any problems:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = @"
{
   ""Name"": ""TestQuery"",
   ""QueryId"": 1,
   ""Parameters"": [
   {
        ""Name"": ""MyString"",
        ""DataType"": 0,
        ""Value"": ""A String"",
        ""IsArray"": false
    }],
   ""Sql"": ""SELECT * FROM Queries""
}";
var query = serializer.Deserialize<Query>(json);
```

Also you can get rid of `[Data*]` attributes from your view models, they are not used by the `JavaScriptSerializer` class.

Comment: I chose a KeyedCollection because all parameters need to be uniquely named, and I want to access them via a Named lookup later on, so it seems to make sense.

Comment: Well, you could use KeyedCollections in your domain models, but in your view models (which is what you are JSON deserializing) you should not. The serializer cannot possibly know what is the key of your dictionaries. You will have to write custom json converters if you want to achieve that. But IMHO you shouldn't be bothered with that.